Дата и время в Compose Multiplatform
Я новичок в Compose Multiplatform и ещё не полностью разобрался во всём интересующем. Мне нужно использовать текущее время устройства, но java.time не поддерживается, также я смотрел в интернете и видел kotlinx.datetime но его также нету, пишет "Unresolved reference: datetime". Посоветуйте, как решить данную проблему.

Подключайте как там описано и пользуйтесь https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-datetime
